# onchange event object undefined in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

anyone know what is another way to do the following code that is okay with IE8?
my follow code is okay in other browsers, but just not in IE8. when in IE8, the evt variable is undefined

```
document.getElementById('ratingDD').onchange = function(evt) {
   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
   alert(evt);
   //console.log(evt);
   if (evt.target.selectedIndex == 0) {
       view.setColumns([0,1,2,3]);
       chart.draw(data, options); 
   }
}
```

on HTML, basically is just a dropdown menu.

```
    <select id="ratingDD">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="team">team</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE, the event is attached to the window, not passed to the function.

Try this for cross-browser support:

```
evt=evt||window.event;
var target=evt.target||evt.srcElement;
```

Comment: ok, got it. It works now, and I learn something today. thanks.